# Lotus Notes: Processing appointment cancellation using ics file

Tags: lotus-notes, icalendar

I am finding it difficult to understand how ics file works in lotus notes. Invitation works precisely as defined whereas in the cancellation event nothing happens.

Say for example, when I import an ics file 2 calendar entries, then the entries are created as expected.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main
DTSTART:20150504T140000
DTEND:20150504T150000
LOCATION:Test - 3
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test - 3
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-us:bvnvn
UID:00EDF2741C3E857965257E39002A2900
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main
DTSTART:20150505T140000
DTEND:20150505T150000
LOCATION:Test - 3
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test - 3
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-us:bvnvn
UID:11EDF2741C3E857965257E39002A2911
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

However, when I try to delete the same calendar entries, using the following ICS file, nothing happens:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main
DTSTART:20150504T140000
DTEND:20150504T150000
LOCATION:Test - 3
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test - 3
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-us:bvnvn
STATUS:CANCELLED
UID:00EDF2741C3E857965257E39002A2900
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main
DTSTART:20150505T140000
DTEND:20150505T150000
LOCATION:Test - 3
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test - 3
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-us:bvnvn
STATUS:CANCELLED
UID:11EDF2741C3E857965257E39002A2911
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The only difference here between the 2 ics files is the method and the status. I have tried the same thing on a google calendar and it simply deletes the appointments after the second import, however, nothing seems to happen when we do so in lotus notes. Is there any field we are suppose to set specially for notes so as to delete the entries?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

As @arnaudq pointed out I was not following the structure correctly.

It had something to do with the naming structure of the organizer field specifically in Notes (since it worked well on google calendar and few other application I tried with).

```
//Wrong Version
ORGANIZER:CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main
//Corrected Version
ORGANIZER;CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main:mailto:CN=Chintan Jayesh Parekh/O=main
```

Hope it is useful to someone facing the same problem.

Comment: Please note that your mailto: URI is still not valid. What you should have after the mailto: scheme is an RFC822 email address (user@domain), not some DN.

Comment: Thanks man..Let me check and update, this seemed to work though.

Comment: It probably works as long as you stay within the Lotus Notes system. But if you want to interoperate with external calendaring systems (gmail, etc...), those addresses won't be understood.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I need a fixture on that..I will update my post accordingly..Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it will solve your problem but:

1. In all of the above, you are missing a DTSTAMP property, with a datetime in UTC corresponding to the date where that particular version of the event was created/modified. And of course, the DTSTAMP for the cancelled version shall be later in time than the original one.
2. In your cancelled events, you are also missing a SEQUENCE property (with a value greater than the one of the original event). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.5 .

Comment: Let me look into this. I do set the sequence property to 1 for cancellaion (just forgot to add it there) but let me see with DTSTAMP. I never went into this, since it seems to WORK WELL WITH GMAIL, so I always believed that it has something to do with notes..